# ZipArchive::addEmptyDir creates an empty file in .zip file

Tags: php, zip, winrar

When i create an .zip archive with bellow code i get an strange empty file. It's ok when i add one file without creating directory. I can open archive, unpack it without errors. I am using WinRar 5.10 (in WinRar 5.0 and lower, 7zip, WinZip there is no problem).

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "test112.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}
$zip->addEmptyDir('test');
$zip->addFile("apache_pb2.png", 'test/test.png');
$zip->close();
```

PrintScreen: [CLICK](http://s13.postimg.org/4fe4d1f9z/Bez_tytu_u.png)

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: There has been apparent success in adding files without creating an empty directory first (that is, the `addEmptyDir` function is only necessary if you need to create the folder without contents.) Could you try commenting out the `$zip->addEmptyDir` line and try running the script again to see what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that by running the `addEmptyDir` function and then running an `addFile` function into the same directory, you are actually creating two instances of `test` in the eyes of some Unzip programs. Generally this won't be an issue, but if you wish to avoid this for your version of WinRAR you should modify your code to the following:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "test112.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

//$zip->addEmptyDir('test'); // Only necessary for directories that will REMAIN empty
$zip->addFile("apache_pb2.png", 'test/test.png');
$zip->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

addEmptyDir from what I'm seeing in old versions and by documentation doesn't create the last "folder" portion of the path as a folder, it creates it as a file instead with no extension.